# Keyboard backlight on Samsung S50 Style

Tags: keyboard, laptop, samsung, backlight

I can't find a way to turn my laptop's keyboard backlight on. It's a Samsung S50 Style with Ubuntu 19.10.

So far, I tried:

- `xset led`
- variations with `xmodmap`
- working with `/sys/class/leds` files
- looking for solutions for other laptops, such as Asus, Sony etc.

None of them worked.

I noticed there is no `/sys/module/samsung*` directory. Am I missing something?